# Htacess Rule for redirect to a URL based on HOST Name

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have configured my project in the server

**Example http://www.example.com**

In that there is one page http://www.example.com/products/index

Now I have other new domain **`http://dev.ny-sample.com`** need to point

I pointed the new domain to **`http://www.example.com/products/index`**

But Now I need to write a rule in my HTACESS File of http://www.example.com/

- If the user type these url http://dev.ny-sample.com then its should redirect to http://dev-nysample.com/products/index

Comment: May this url might help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235711/htacess-rule-for-redirect-to-a-url-based-on-host-name]

Comment: @Sri Please give the url.. Its redirecting to same page

Comment: very sorry [http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/242/How+do+I+redirect+my+site+using+a+.htaccess+file%3F] this url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I made this way in my index.php

if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] =='dev.ny-sample.com' && ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == "/"))
{
    header('Location: http://dev.ny-sample.com/products/index/');
}

I tried all the htaccess way it didn't worked for me, May be I don't know the right way.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?nysample\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/products/index [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it, It is working fine for me.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/product/index [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c >

RewriteEngine On

Redirect / http://dev-nysample.com/products/index

<IfModule>